# Accessing Gurobi solver status with Pyomo

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, gurobi

I'm working on an optimization problem using Pyomo and Gurobi as the solver. I have a for loop where I iterate over multiple timesteps and solve the optimization problem for each timestep. I want to handle cases where the solver returns an infeasible solution and save the dataframe in those instances. I'm looking for guidance on how to properly handle infeasible solutions and save the dataframe when such a case arises.

This is an example of the code:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverStatus, TerminationCondition
from pyomo.util.infeasible import log_infeasible_constraints

...
opt_option['solver'] = 'gurobi'

model_1stlayer.solver = SolverFactory(opt_options['solver'])
model_results = model_1stlayer.solver.solve(
    model_1stlayer,
    options=solver_options,
    tee=True
)

if (model_1stlayer.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
    save_df = True
    filename = os.path.join(output_path, 'df_operation.xlsx')
    df_operation.to_excel(filename)
    filename = os.path.join(output_path, 'df_operation_2ndLayer.xlsx')
    df_operation_2ndLayer.to_excel(filename)
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...main.py", line 456, in <module>
    if (model_1stlayer.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
AttributeError: 'GUROBISHELL' object has no attribute 'termination_condition'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a format like this, which interrogates the results object.

The below works with `cbc` when checking for optimal.  I think you should be able to just change out the solver and the condition name.

It isn't very eloquent.  There is likely a cleaner way, but this works.  I'm not sure if the `solver.terminal_condition` you are trying to access has been removed from the project...

```
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
res = solver.solve(m)
# ensure the result is optimal
status = res.Solver()['Termination condition'].value
assert(status == 'optimal', f'error occurred, status: {status}.  Check model!')
```